# How to automatically create multiple versions of a document with different paper sizes & reflecting this in the generated PDF filename?

Tags: moderncv, automation, latexmk, shell-escape

I am using the `moderncv` class to prepare my resume for applying to jobs in the US (where the standard paper size is `letter`), and in UK (where the standard paper size is `A4`).

Here is a `MWE` file called `main.tex`.

```
% some preamble stuff before `documentclass` line
% blah blah (preamble)
% more blah blah (preamble)

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  % <----- paper size is set here.

% a lot more preamble lines after `documentclass` line
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\address{83 Fancy Avenue}{Noweheresville}{Gotham City 24061} 
\phone[mobile]{123 456 7890}
\email{someone@xyz.com}
\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{example-image-a}


\begin{document}
   \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

As shown in the `MWE`, some of my custom preamble precedes the `documentclass` line, whilst some others comes after it.

I am using `latexmk` to compile the document with `lualatex`. How can I maintain just a **single** `tex` source and automatically build two different versions of the PDF document each **appropriately named** `Resume_A4paper.pdf` and `Resume_letterpaper.pdf`? I am happy to use any `directlua` magic and/or external tools to facilitate this.

#### Rationale

With the present content, I have manually checked that the page layout is okay for both A4/letter sizes. I just want to automate this process for future minor tweaks (modifying one or two bullet points in the whole CV to tailor to each job description). It would be tedious to manually produce 2 different versions for each type of job/industry I am applying for.

Comment: In my view a CV should be carefully checked for layout changes, so automatically changing paper size is quite a huge step to take. But why don't you simply set up a one-line file, read its content before `\documentclass` and then pass it as option?

Comment: @TeXnician I have manually checked the layout with the present content, and the page layout is okay for both A4/letter sizes. I just want to automate this process for any minor tweaks (modifying one or two bullet points in the whole CV to tailor to each job description). Sorry, but I do not understand your suggestion in the 2nd half of your comment.

Comment: Why don't put your personal data in another file to input and create two main files with paper size in name and compile both?

Comment: @Sigur Ok. Can `latexmk` be used here? Also, is this amenable to the suitable automatic naming of the output PDFs?

Comment: @Krishna, since you'll have two main files also two output pdf's. You can compile two main files with `pdflatex main-a4.tex main-letter.tex` for example.

Comment: @Sigur Thank you. How can I configure `latexmk` for this purpose?

Comment: @Krishna, sorry, I never had used `latexmk`.

Comment: You say that the content fits on both A4 and letterpaper. If it looks reasonable on both then I don't see any need to produce two different PDF files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When on my system I save the following example as **test.tex** and on the shell (via `chdir` or `cd` or whatever) change the active directory to the directory where **test.tex** is stored, and then compile **test.tex** by calling **latexmk** from the shell/command-line via

```
latexmk -cd -gg -pdflatex="lualatex --shell-escape %O %S" -pdf -dvi- -ps- test.tex
```

(maybe on your platform you need `--enable-write18` instead of `--shell-escape`)

, then during the first **lualatex**-run initiated by **latexmk**, where aux-files don't exist in the beginning, another **latexmk**-run is initiated where the `-jobname`-option is used for attaching the phrase `-letterpaper` to the current expansion of `\jobname`.

In any case it is checked whether the expansion of the `\jobname`-primitive contains the phrase `-letterpaper`.

If so, the option "letterpaper" is passed to the documentclass.

If not so, the option "a4paper" is passed to the documentclass.

As a result you have one **latexmk**-run on **test.tex** which exactly once initiates another **latexmk**-run on **test.tex** with `-jobname="test-letterpaper"`.

In the end you get **test.pdf** which is a4paper and **test-letterpaper.pdf** which is letterpaper.

If you wish, you can provide the `-jobname`-option on the shell/command-line also and e.g., do

```
latexmk -cd -gg -jobname="test-a4paper" -pdflatex="lualatex --shell-escape %O %S" -pdf -dvi- -ps- test.tex
```

(maybe on your platform you need `--enable-write18` instead of `--shell-escape`)

in order to get **test-a4paper.pdf** and **test-letterpaper.pdf**.

```
\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{shellesc}% more recent releases of LuaTeX don't provide
                         % \write18 any more. This package makes sure
                         % under such LuaTeX \write18 is emulated by
                         % calls to \directlua.
\newcommand\CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
}%
\newcommand\letterpaperphrase{-letterpaper}\@onelevel@sanitize\letterpaperphrase
\newcommand\Afourpaperphrase{-a4paper}\@onelevel@sanitize\Afourpaperphrase
%
\newcommand\gobbletoletterpaperphrase{}%
\expandafter\long\expandafter\def
\expandafter\gobbletoletterpaperphrase\expandafter#\expandafter1\letterpaperphrase{}%
%
\newcommand\gobbletoAfourpaperphrase{}%
\expandafter\long\expandafter\def
\expandafter\gobbletoAfourpaperphrase\expandafter#\expandafter1\Afourpaperphrase{}%
%
\newcommand\keepBeforeAfourpaperphrase{}%
\expandafter\long\expandafter\def
\expandafter\keepBeforeAfourpaperphrase
\expandafter#\expandafter1\Afourpaperphrase#2\relax{#1}%
%
\newcommand\CheckWhetherJobNameHasLetterpaperphrase{}%
\expandafter\def
\expandafter\CheckWhetherJobNameHasLetterpaperphrase
\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{%
     \romannumeral0\@firstofone{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter} %
     \expandafter\gobbletoletterpaperphrase
     \romannumeral0\@firstofone{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter} %
     \expandafter\jobname
     \letterpaperphrase
  }%
  { \@secondoftwo}%
  { \@firstoftwo}%
}%
\newcommand\CheckWhetherJobNameHasAfourpaperphrase{}%
\expandafter\def
\expandafter\CheckWhetherJobNameHasAfourpaperphrase
\expandafter{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{%
     \romannumeral0\@firstofone{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter} %
     \expandafter\gobbletoAfourpaperphrase
     \romannumeral0\@firstofone{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter} %
     \expandafter\jobname
     \Afourpaperphrase
  }%
  { \@secondoftwo}%
  { \@firstoftwo}%
}%
\CheckWhetherJobNameHasLetterpaperphrase{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{letterpaper}{moderncv}%
}{%
  \PassOptionsToClass{a4paper}{moderncv}%
}%
\IfFileExists{\jobname.tex}{%
  \newcommand\myinfile{\jobname.tex}%
}{%
  \newcommand\myinfile{%
    \CheckWhetherJobNameHasAfourpaperphrase
      {\expandafter\keepBeforeAfourpaperphrase\jobname\relax}%
      {\jobname}.tex%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\createletterdocument{%
  \ShellEscape{%
    latexmk -cd
            -gg
            -jobname="\CheckWhetherJobNameHasAfourpaperphrase
                        {\expandafter\keepBeforeAfourpaperphrase\jobname\relax}%
                        {\jobname}%
                      \letterpaperphrase" 
            -pdflatex="lualatex \@percentchar O \@percentchar S" 
            -pdf -dvi- -ps- 
            \myinfile
  }%
}%
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \begingroup
  \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\global\string\let\string\createletterdocument=\string\empty}%
  \endgroup
  \CheckWhetherJobNameHasLetterpaperphrase{}{\createletterdocument}%
}%
\makeatother

% some preamble stuff before `documentclass` line
% blah blah (preamble)
% more blah blah (preamble)

\documentclass[11pt,sans]{moderncv}  % <----- paper size is _not_ 
% set here but is set via \PassOptionsToClass.

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{pdfpagewidth}{}{\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\@ifundefined{pdfpageheight}{}{\pdfpageheight=\paperheight}%
\@ifundefined{pagewidth}{}{\pagewidth=\paperwidth}%
\@ifundefined{pageheight}{}{\pageheight=\paperheight}%
\makeatother

% a lot more preamble lines after `documentclass` line
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\address{83 Fancy Avenue}{Noweheresville}{Gotham City 24061} 
\phone[mobile]{123 456 7890}
\email{someone@xyz.com}
\photo[64pt][0.5pt]{example-image-a}


\begin{document}
   \makecvtitle
\end{document}
```