# LaTeX conditional processing via command line arguments

Tags: conditionals

I use Beamer presentations in workshops where I set questions, have students work on the answers, and then display some sample answers. I give the students a version of the presentation without the answers, so they can read back through the presentation as needed.

It seems the usual way of doing such conditional processing in LaTeX would be to define a command to mark up an answer and then provide two definitions of the command, one that includes the answers and another that omits the answers. The usual way of switching between these definitions is to use distinct top-level source files.

I would prefer to avoid creating an extra top-level source file for each presentation and instead control the formatting behaviour using command line arguments, an environment variable, or such like. Then I could write a script to format the presentation twice, once with the answers and once without answers.

Looking through the [arguments of pdflatex](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdflatex), I don't see a way of passing a flag that could be used in the LaTeX source to choose between the definitions.

Related questions and solutions:

- [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document) has answers that solve my problem, but the question does not express the context and requirements as clearly as the question here.
- [Conditional text lines latex document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595650/conditional-text-lines-latex-document) - expresses a similar requirement.
- The [exam package](https://ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=en) - seems to require multiple top-level source files.

Comment: You can use the commandline-option --jobname for assigning a filename for the .log-file, the .aux-file and the pdf-file. So for different variants of your document you can provide different jobnames. By parsing the expansion of the `\jobname`-primitive you can detect the variant of your document which LaTeX is about to create. I did his in [my answer to How to automatically create multiple versions of a document with different paper sizes & reflecting this in the generated PDF filename?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/475567/118714)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line is taken as Tex source code, unless it consists purely of letters in which case it is taken as a filename with an implicit `\input`

so you can do

```
pdflatex '\def\opta{1} \def\optb{yes} \input{file}'
```

and in the body of `file.tex` test the values of `\opta` and `\optb`. You may need different quote characters, or use `\\`  in place of `\`  depending on the commandline shell that you use.

Answer (score 0):

When on my system I save the following example as **test.tex** and on the shell (via `chdir` or `cd` or whatever) change the active directory to the directory where **test.tex** is stored, and then compile **test.tex** by calling **latexmk** from the shell/command-line via

```
latexmk -cd -gg -pdflatex="lualatex --shell-escape %O %S" -pdf test.tex
```

(maybe on your platform you need `--enable-write18` instead of `--shell-escape`)

, then during the first **lualatex**-run initiated by **latexmk**, where aux-files don't exist in the beginning, another **latexmk**-run is initiated where the `-jobname`-option is used for attaching the phrase `_WithAnswers` to the current expansion of `\jobname`.

In any case it is checked whether the expansion of the `\jobname`-primitive contains the phrase `_WithAnswers`.

If so, the switch `\ifWithAnswers` is set to "true".

If not so, the switch `\ifWithAnswers` is set to "false".

As a result you have one **latexmk**-run on **test.tex** which exactly once initiates another **latexmk**-run on **test.tex** with `-jobname="test_WithAnswers"`.

In the end you get **test.pdf** which is without answers and **test_WithAnswers.pdf** which is with answers.

```latex
%=======================================================================================================
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \CheckWhetherJobnameContainsPhrase #1 {
  \exp_args:Nne \use:nn {\str_if_in:nnTF} {{\jobname} {#1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newif\ifWithAnswers

\CheckWhetherJobnameContainsPhrase{_WithAnswers}{%
  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % Stuff in case the document is to be created with answers
  %............................................................................
  \WithAnswerstrue
}{%
  %----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  % Stuff in case the document is to be created without answers
  %............................................................................
  % - Let's call another instance of latexmk for creating the document-variant
  %   with answers:
  %............................................................................
  %  (Let's do things when the.aux-files are already read.)
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \immediate\write\csname @mainaux\endcsname{\string\providecommand\string\DoOnlyInFirstLaTeXRun[1]{}}%
    \providecommand\DoOnlyInFirstLaTeXRun[1]{#1}%
    \DoOnlyInFirstLaTeXRun{%
      \RequirePackage{shellesc}% more recent releases of LuaTeX don't provide
                               % \write18 any more. This package makes sure
                               % under such LuaTeX \write18 is emulated by
                               % calls to \directlua.
      \ShellEscape{%
        latexmk -cd
                -jobname="\jobname\string_WithAnswers"
                -pdflatex="lualatex \csname @percentchar\endcsname O \csname @percentchar\endcsname S"
                -pdf
                \jobname.tex
      }%
    }%
  }%
  %............................................................................
  \WithAnswersfalse
}
%=======================================================================================================

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

  This is a text.

  \ifWithAnswers 
    It comes with answers.
  \else
    It comes without answers.
  \fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This would work, but isn't as clean as David Carlisle's answer IMO.